# Airflow Deferred Operator: too many values to unpack (expected 2). Debugging trigger

Tags: python, airflow

I am trying out deferred operators on Airflow

```
import asyncio
from random import randint
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.sensors.base import BaseSensorOperator
from airflow.triggers.base import BaseTrigger, TriggerEvent
from work import default_args, default_start_date

class RandomTrigger(BaseTrigger):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def serialize(self):
        return ("airflow.triggers.random.RandomTrigger")

    async def run(self):
        randomNumber = None
        while True:
            randomNumber = randint(0, 10)
            print(f"Random number is {randomNumber}")
            if randomNumber < 8:
                await asyncio.sleep(1)
            else:
                break
        yield TriggerEvent(f"{randomNumber} > 8")

class WaitForCompletionSensor(BaseSensorOperator):
    def execute(self, context):
        self.defer(trigger=RandomTrigger(), method_name="execute_complete")

    def execute_complete(self, context, event=None):
        return

with DAG(
    'dag10-deferred-operators',
    description = 'Try using deferred operators/triggers',
    default_args = default_args,
    start_date = default_start_date,
    schedule_interval = None,
    catchup=False,
) as dag:
    wait = WaitForCompletionSensor(
        task_id="wait"
    )

    wait
```

However I get an error thats quite vague, where did I go wrong?

```
[2022-06-19, 18:27:00 +08] {standard_task_runner.py:92} ERROR - Failed to execute job 100 for task wait (too many values to unpack (expected 2); 107)
[2022-06-19, 18:27:00 +08] {local_task_job.py:156} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2022-06-19, 18:27:00 +08] {taskinstance.py:1395} INFO - Marking task as UP_FOR_RETRY. dag_id=dag10-deferred-operators, task_id=wait, execution_date=20220619T101529, start_date=20220619T102700, end_date=20220619T102700
[2022-06-19, 18:27:00 +08] {local_task_job.py:273} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

**UPDATE**

Seems like in serialize, I need to have another param

```
class RandomTrigger(BaseTrigger):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def serialize(self):
        return ("airflow.triggers.random.RandomTrigger", None)
                                                         ^ HERE
```

But why is that?

But even then, in logs now it says

```
[2022-06-19, 18:32:49 +08] {taskinstance.py:1459} INFO - Pausing task as DEFERRED. dag_id=dag10-deferred-operators, task_id=wait, execution_date=20220619T103248, start_date=20220619T103249
[2022-06-19, 18:32:49 +08] {local_task_job.py:156} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
[2022-06-19, 18:32:49 +08] {local_task_job.py:273} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

Which looks ok, but the UI shows that task is up for retry, why is that?

Answer (score 0):

based on documentation: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/deferring.html#writing-triggers
it seams you need to write **init** and serialize methods in pairs - that means, that you pass to your serialize methods params which are then used to re-instantiate the triggerer. Thats why you can pass None - as you dont have any class fields to begin with.